# How to eliminate duplicates on util class for 2 different class

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, lombok

I declared 2 classes which have same members but separated for some reasons. And I implemented an util class to convert those 2 classes to 1 same class like below.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class VO1 {
  private int id;
  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  ...
  private String value20;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class VO2 {
  private int id;
  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  ...
  private String value20;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class DomainEntity {
  private int id;
  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  ...
  private String value15;
}

public class Converter {
  public static DomainEntity fromVO1(VO1 vo1) {
    return DomainEntity.builder.id(vo1.getId())
             .value1(vo1.getValue1())
             .value2(vo1.getValue2())
             ...
             .value15(vo1.getValue15())
             .build();
  }

  public static DomainEntity fromVO2(VO2 vo2) {
    return DomainEntity.builder.id(vo2.getId())
             .value1(vo2.getValue1())
             .value2(vo2.getValue2())
             ...
             .value15(vo2.getValue15())
             .build();
  }
}
```

Now I have code duplicates in 'Converter', I want to eliminate them. Of course I know I can use inheritance to remove it. However I also want to use 'Lombok', since those classes have many properties. And using inheritance makes using 'Lombok' messier. Does anyone know the elegant way to solve this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: can you explain messier part when using interface,  you can use interface + generics with on method in Converter class

Comment: Using inheritance with Lombok, for example to use builder, I need to declare constructor with all arguments and need to rename builder also which I don't want to do.

Comment: I don't think it will make code messier , I had given a try , using inheritance, I am posting my code as answer because comments will not show code efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example using inheritance,I don't feel code gets messier , am i missing something ?

**for inheritance you could use experimental @SuperBuilder**

```
       package lombok;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @SuperBuilder
        public class BaseVO {


            private String s1;
            private String s2;
            private String s3;
            private String s4;
            private String s5;
            private String s6;
            private String s7;
            private String s8;
            private String s9;

        }


        package lombok;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @SuperBuilder
        public class VO1 extends BaseVO{

            private String vo1Specific;
        }


        package lombok;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @SuperBuilder
        public class VO2 extends BaseVO {

            private String vo2Specific;
        }

        package lombok;

        @Builder
        @ToString
        public class DomainEntity {

            private String s1;
            private String s2;
            private String s3;
            private String s4;
            private String s5;
            private String s6;
            private String s7;
            private String s8;
            private String s9;
            private String specific;

        }


package lombok;

import lombok.DomainEntity.DomainEntityBuilder;

public class Converter {

    public static <T extends BaseVO> DomainEntity fromVO(T basevo) {

        DomainEntityBuilder builder = DomainEntity.builder();
        builder.s1(basevo.getS1()).s2(basevo.getS2()).s3(basevo.getS3());

        if (basevo instanceof VO1) {
            VO1 vo1 = (VO1) basevo;
            builder.specific(vo1.getVo1Specific());

        }

        if (basevo instanceof VO2) {
            VO2 vo1 = (VO2) basevo;
            builder.specific(vo1.getVo2Specific());

        }

        return builder.build();

    }

}

        package lombok;

        public class App {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

            VO1 vo1 = VO1.builder().s1("VO1S1").vo1Specific("VO1 specific property").build();

            VO2 vo2 = VO2.builder().s1("VO2S1").vo2Specific("VO2 specific property").build();

            DomainEntity d1 = Converter.<VO1>fromVO(vo1);
            System.out.println(" d1 " + d1);
            DomainEntity d2 = Converter.<VO2>fromVO(vo2);

            System.out.println(" d2 " + d2);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I think you miss 'builder' on VO1 and VO2, cause I need to convert DomainEntity to VO1 or VO2, they also need to have builder. But if they use BASEVO as super class, they can't just use '@Builder' annotation. I need to write constructor with all arguments and rename the 'builder' not to duplicate with builder of BASEVO. Which ruins the purpose of using lombok, not writing the boilerplate codes.

Comment: I now understood, I have modified my example probably you can use experimental @SuperBuilder

Comment: I have modified my example using @SuperBuilder

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Unfortunately intellij doesn't support @superbuilder yet. So I was looking for another way which can be achieved by different design patter or something else.

Comment: yes, Intellij doesn't support that , but IMHO an IDE should not be a deciding factor for your design decisions, switch to STS or eclipse.

Comment: I can only think of Decorator Pattern where VO1 and VO2 can act as decorator , alternative you can go to old school until intelliJ starts supporting it

Comment: Even though your suggestion doesn't work for me, it could work for somebody else. So I'll choose yours as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an interface with getters for all values and then both value objects should implement it. Then in Converter you can use reference to this interface in one method which is reusable twice.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I knew I could do that with interface but I don't want to write all the getter and setter myself and that's why I'm using Lombok. So I'm looking for an elegant way.